# App 'can’t be opened because its integrity cannot be verified' on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, electron, macos-catalina

Some users reported that my app cannot open in macOS Catalina, with the error message:

> MyApp can’t be opened because its integrity cannot be verified.

Is this because of notarization? The app seems to be working on other macOS versions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed the error is because of notarization. I also got this error a few weeks ago. You need to notarize your application.

I stumbled upon [this awesome article](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2019/electron/notarizing-your-electron-application/) that explains how to notarize the app. Steps would be too long to describe here.

I also have an active GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/Nishkalkashyap/Quark-electron) that has implemented notarization, feel free to check it out. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Do we need to notarize app before uploading to App store? From some articles I read seems we only need to notarize for non-appstore distributions.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'm distributing my app outside appstore.

Comment: Do we need to notarize if the app is being distributed outside app store ?

Comment: @Ajey YES!. It is now a requirement to notarize your apps since MacOS 10.14.5.

Comment: Update - the issue was due to code signing in my case - I missed code signing for some binaries.

Comment: @BruceXindaLin So apps do not need to be notarized for Mac App Store?

Comment: @kspearrin Nop. For MAS build there is no need to be notarized

Answer (score 0):

This is because of recent changes in macOS Catalina.

```
sudo spctl --add "Path_to_flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/libimobiledevice/idevice_id"
```

You might need to reboot the system in order to apply the changes.

You can run [a GateKeeper script](https://github.com/AmirKamali/Flutter_GateKeeper_Fix) to fix the issue.

I have [published an article](https://medium.com/@amir.n3t/how-to-fix-flutter-idevice-id-running-errors-in-mac-osx-catalina-7aa1f89f61aa) with more information how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when both `alpha` and `beta` versions were installed on the device and what helped was to remove all of them and install them from scratch.